# integer to string conversion / integer-string concatenation in C++ - more compact solutions?

Tags: c++, string, casting, int

How to do integer -> string conversion has been answered many times on the internet... however, I'm looking for the most compact "C++-way" to do this.

Since you're able to concatenate strings using the overloaded + operator, it would be preferable to be able to do something along the lines of the python-ish
x = (stringVariable + str(intVariable)) concatenation, but I don't know if there's a canonical way to do this in C++.

The most common solutions I see are:

stringstream: If possible, it would be nice not to have 3 lines of code (declaration, writing to the stream, conversion to string) just to concatenate some letters and numbers.

itoa: this works, but I'm looking for a canonical C++ solution. Also, I think itoa is technically non-standard although I could be wrong.

boost format / boost lexical cast: this works too, but is there nothing in vanilla C++ that does the job?

Comment: Note that stringstreams actually do the job. Hint: Don't invent (non-)problems. :)

Comment: @Kos Just a pet peeve of mine, but its `std::ostringstream` which does the job here.

Comment: @JamesKanze: To really nitpick, the actual job of converting is done in the appropriate `operator<<` on ostreams.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
#include <string>
```

String to integer: `int n = std::stoi(s);`

Integer to string: `std::string s = std::to_string(n);`

Comment: Cool, yet another new feature I haven't yet known (it's worth mentioning though that it's officially not even 1 year old and some compilers or compiler users might not yet have caught up!).

Comment: @Kos: Officially it is 3.5 months old ;) (2011-09-01)

Comment: C++11 is making my code a lot more maintenance-friendly. Hopefully being an early adopter doesn't come back to bite me (in terms of compiler support, company coding standards, etc.).

Comment: @daj: Well, at least it'll bite you less and less as time goes by!

Answer (score 4):

C++11 has `std::to_string`, but in C++03 there is no "single function call solution". Also `boost::lexical_cast` (although specialized for certain cases) and `std::to_string` ultimately call `operator<<(std::ostream&,T)` for any T they should convert. It is all about being able to generically handle things, and when `op<<` is already there, why not reuse it to create a string representation?

Answer (score 2):

`stringVariable + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( intVariable )` would do the trick, but I'm not sure that this is such a good idea.   Even in Python, something like `'{}{:6f}'.format( stringVariable, intVariable )` would be far more usual.

Answer (score 0):

What's the matter with having 3 lines to convert ? If you need to use the same type of concatenation anytime, just put it into a function and it's done. It would be better than to use strange solutions.