# C++ How do you change an integer to a string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to itoa() for converting integer to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c)

How do you change an integer to a string in c++?

Comment: Check the reference here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577275/integer-to-string-conversion-integer-string-concatenation-in-c-more-compac

Comment: For conversion like these, I have a bookmark https://www.converttypes.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard C++ library style:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

(...)

int number = 5;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << number;
std::string numberAsString(ss.str());
```

Or if you're lucky enough to be using C++11:

```
#include <string>

(...)

int number = 5;
std::string numberAsString = std::to_string(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...)` to get a char[], then use `string(char*)` get string.
Of course，there're other ways.